Woocommerce: 403 Error When Sending API Request to Gateway Endpoint
I am developing a WooCommerce custom payment-method plugin that redirects customers to a payment gateway through RESTful web services. The integration requires an API key (Token) provided by the gateway platform. According to the documentation:
A POST request must be sent to the API endpoint (https://api.example.com/api/v1/payment-terminal/).
The request requires the customer's phone number in the "username" field (text type).
And a successful response should look like this:
  "status": 200,
  "error": "",
  "message": "",
  "data": {
    "cash_wallt": 0,
    "special_amount": 0
  },
  "patch": [],
  "date": "2024-10-16 12:57:47"
}

Here is the relevant function from my plugin:
public function process_payment($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $amount = $order->get_total();
    $description = sprintf(__('Order #%s', 'woocommerce'), $order->get_order_number());
    $customer_phone = $order->get_billing_phone();

    // Step 1: Check Customer Credit
    $credit_response = wp_remote_post('https://api.example.com/api/v1/payment-terminal/', [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->apikey, // API key
            'Content-Type'  => 'application/json'
        ],
        'body' => json_encode(['username' => $customer_phone]) // Customer phone number
    ]);

    if (is_wp_error($credit_response)) {
        wc_add_notice('Authentication error', 'error');  
        return;
    }

    $credit_body = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($credit_response), true);
    if ($credit_body['status'] != 200) {
        wc_add_notice('Failed Authentication', 'error'); 
        return;
    }
    
}



At this stage, I consistently run into a 403 Forbidden error when an order is submitted at checkout, with this gateway selected.
I’ve already double-checked and verified the following:
API Key (Token) is correct and included in the request header.
Phone Number matches a registered account on the gateway platform.
The server IP has been whitelisted.
To ensure the issue isn’t plugin-related, I even tried a direct request using curl:
curl -X POST https://api.example.com/api/v1/payment-terminal/ \
-H "Authorization: Bearer {token}" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d "{\"username\": \"{phone number}\"}"


the response was:
{
  "status": 403,
  "error": null,
  "message": "permission denied",
  "data": [],
  "patch": [],
  "date": "2024-12-09 20:13:21"
}

I've scratched my head to find out the reason behind this frustrating issue, but to no avail. Any hint to find a solution would be appreciated.
The Documentation Mentioned Above

Introduction: All web services described in this documentation are
RESTful.
Authentication: To authenticate with the service, you must use the
apikey token in the headers of the requests. The token must be
obtained from our personnel. When defining the token, our personnel
will require you to specify the callback URL of your website. All
requests are of the POST type.
Checking Balance on our platform When making a request to this endpoint, you
will receive the user's cash wallet balance and special credit balance
in our platform. Please note that payments are processed exclusively
through the wallet on our platform.
Required Request Fields:
Field Name: username Description: User's phone number Type: Text
Request Path: api.[gateway].com/api/v1/payment-terminal/
Successful Response Example: The response will show the user's
cash_wallt (cash wallet balance) and special_amount (special credit
balance).


Link to the mentioned documentation?

@C3roe
I added the related part of the above-mentioned documentation at the end

And they want the authentication via an Authorization: Bearer header, and not something else perhaps?

Yes, that's exactly the initial step they require. I've also tried using the X-API-Key header instead of Authorization: Bearer, but I still the same result

Then you should probably contact their support, and ask them if there is any issue with your token.

I just tested with a new token, unfortunately the problem still remains

I am convinced that the issue is not on my side, as I am sending a simple POST request through a script with a token in the header, from a whitelisted server IP, containing a phone number passed as the username, to the API endpoint and still get 403 error.

Even more reason to talk to their support and asking them, whether they can see any issues with your token / account, on their end.
